# why *ngIf doesnt'work with ng-template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng-template

I have a condition in the template as follows:

```
<ng-container>
    <p *ngFor="let seat of InfoDetails?.seatInfo">
        <template *ngIf="seat.section">
            Section {{seat?.section}} ,
        </template>
        <template *ngIf="seat.row">
            Row {{seat?.row}},
        </template>
        <template *ngIf="seat.seatNo">
            Seat number {{seat?.seatNo}}
        </template>
    </p>
</ng-container>
```

I have dataset that contains `row` and `seatNo`, but it does not seem to print in the template. what is the issue here?

Comment: What are the preferred values for `seat.section` because you should do a comparison in that case

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe I do not think its necessary, i just need to check if value is present or not

Comment: It is necessary, depending on the type of the value you will be checking for Eg: String, Array, Number etc.

Comment: its a  string here

Comment: if you are using `ngIf` what is a need of another if condition seat`?`.section and on template you have to use `ngIf` as @Fetra R said

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Read the doc here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives especially for

> `<div *ngIf="hero" >{{hero.name}}</div>`
>
> The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more
>   complicated. Internally, Angular desugars it in two stages. First, it
>   translates the *ngIf="..." into a template attribute, template="ngIf
>   ...",  like this.
>
> `<div template="ngIf hero">{{hero.name}}</div>`
>
> Then it translates the template attribute into a 
>   element, wrapped around the host element, like this.
>
> `<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">  <div>{{hero.name}}</div></ng-template>`
>
> - The *ngIf directive moved to the  element where it    became a property binding,[ngIf].
> - The rest of the , including    its class attribute, moved inside the  element.

So for it we have `ng-container`

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="seat.section">
    Section {{seat.section}} ,
 </ng-container>
```

or use span or div or regular html tag.

```
 <span *ngIf="seat.section">
    Section {{seat.section}} ,
 </span>
```

or if you still want to use ng-template ([not recommended](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#prefer-the-asterisk--syntax))

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="seat.section">
  Section {{seat.section}} ,
</ng-template>
```

Comment: 'ng-template' is not a known element:

Comment: answer by @Fetra R. is a way to go for this question- 
<ng-container>
  <p *ngFor="let seat of InfoDetails?.seatInfo">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="seat.section">
      Section {{seat?.section}} ,
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template [ngIf]="seat.row">
      Row {{seat?.row}},
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template [ngIf]="seat.seatNo">
      Seat number {{seat?.seatNo}}
    </ng-template>
  </p>
</ng-container>

Comment: If ng-template is not recognized use template, you may use an older version than angular4.0.0-rc.1       https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Someone here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478041/using-ng-template-for-ngif#47478041 wants to know why you say it's not recommended to use the ng-template.