# Compound If statement not evaluating to true Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement

I have the following block of code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of model">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let columnDataName of columnDataNames">
            <td *ngIf="modelConfig[columnDataName] && modelConfig[columnDataName].isVisible">
                <ng-template *ngIf="showRowTextBox && columnDataName === conditionalInputName || columnDataName === conditionCheckBoxName; else otherColumns">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="columnDataName === conditionalInputName">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here" [hidden]="!chkEnabled?.checked" (focusout)="onTextBoxFocusOut(row[primaryKeyColumnName], $event)" />
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="columnDataName === conditionCheckBoxName">
                        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="chkAll?.checked" #chkEnabled ngModel />
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #otherColumns>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="modelConfig[columnDataName].isDate;">
                        {{ row[columnDataName] | date:'d MMM yyyy' }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="modelConfig[columnDataName].isBoolean;">
                        <tfg-toggle onText="Yes" offText="No" [disabled]="true" [value]="row[columnDataName]"></tfg-toggle>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="!modelConfig[columnDataName].isBoolean && !modelConfig[columnDataName].isDate">
                        {{ row[columnDataName] }}
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-template>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <td *ngFor="let buttonColumnName of buttonColumnNames">
            <button (click)="executeButtonFunction(row[primaryKeyColumnName], buttonColumnName)" class="btn" [ngClass]="buttonColumnName === 'Delete' ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary'">{{buttonColumnName}}</button>
        </td>
        <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="showRowTextBox">
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here" [hidden]="!chkEnabled.checked" (focusout)="onTextBoxFocusOut(row[primaryKeyColumnName], $event)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" [checked]="chkAll?.checked" #chkEnabled ngModel/>
            </td>
          </ng-container> -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The page does not render as expected, because the `if` statement below does not evaluate to true.

```
<ng-template *ngIf="showRowTextBox && columnDataName === conditionalInputName || columnDataName === conditionCheckBoxName; else otherColumns">
```

The `ShowRowTextBox` is set to true, and at some point of the iteration, the `columnDataName` will either be equal to the `conditionalInputName` or `condtionCheckBoxName`.

Is my logic incorrect?

Comment: Refer this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837756/why-ngif-doesntwork-with-ng-template

Comment: Is this, what you're looking for?    <ng-template *ngIf="showRowTextBox && (columnDataName === conditionalInputName || columnDataName === conditionCheckBoxName); else otherColumns">

Comment: @Neyxo I have tried formatting my statement as you suggested, but it still evaluates to false

Comment: @Neyxo would that really make a difference? `true && false || true` is going to give the same output as `true && (false || true)`. Same if you swap the OR conditions.

Comment: @vlaz Right, makes sense. I hadn't thought of the precedence.

Comment: @Maheswaran the link you provided seemed to have solved my issue, will post my answer soon.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you can use the safe navigation operator instead of `modelConfig[columnDataName] && modelConfig[columnDataName].isVisible`, giving you `modelConfig[columnDataName]?.isVisible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837756/why-ngif-doesntwork-with-ng-template) article, I changed my markup as follow:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of model">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let columnDataName of columnDataNames">
        <td *ngIf="modelConfig[columnDataName] && modelConfig[columnDataName].isVisible">
          <ng-container *ngIf="showRowTextBox && (columnDataName === conditionalInputName || columnDataName === conditionCheckBoxName); else otherColumns">
            <ng-container *ngIf="columnDataName === conditionalInputName">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here" [hidden]="!chkEnabled?.checked" (focusout)="onTextBoxFocusOut(row[primaryKeyColumnName], $event)"/>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="columnDataName === conditionCheckBoxName">
              <input type="checkbox" #chkEnabled ngModel/>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #otherColumns>
            <ng-container *ngIf="modelConfig[columnDataName].isDate;">
              {{ row[columnDataName] | date:'d MMM yyyy' }}
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="modelConfig[columnDataName].isBoolean;">
              <tfg-toggle onText="Yes" offText="No" [disabled]="true" [value]="row[columnDataName]"></tfg-toggle>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!modelConfig[columnDataName].isBoolean && !modelConfig[columnDataName].isDate">
              {{ row[columnDataName] }}
            </ng-container>
          </ng-template>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <td *ngFor="let buttonColumnName of buttonColumnNames">
        <button (click)="executeButtonFunction(row[primaryKeyColumnName], buttonColumnName)" class="btn" [ngClass]="buttonColumnName === 'Delete' ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary'">{{buttonColumnName}}</button>
      </td>
      <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="showRowTextBox">
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here" [hidden]="!chkEnabled.checked" (focusout)="onTextBoxFocusOut(row[primaryKeyColumnName], $event)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" [checked]="chkAll?.checked" #chkEnabled ngModel/>
        </td>
      </ng-container> -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Yes it is, replacing the first <ng-template> to be an <ng-container> seemed to have solved the problem