# Angular 8: Not Showing the content of ng-tmplate in nested structure

Tags: angular, ng-template, nebular, ng-container

I have a model that in its structure has a list and one enum property like this:

```
export class myModel {
    Items: any[]=[];
    ItemsType: ItemType;
}
```

and I want to show the list of my model in the template with ng-container and ng-template but inner content of ng-template not showing in my result
my template is like this:

```
<nb-accordion>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let model of myModels">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="model.itemType == 0">
      <nb-accordion-item *ngFor="let item of model.Items">
        <nb-accordion-item-header>
          ...some content
        </nb-accordion-item-header>
        <nb-accordion-item-body>
          ...some content
        </nb-accordion-item-body>
      </nb-accordion-item>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template [ngIf]="model.itemType == 1">
      <nb-accordion-item *ngFor="let item of model.socialNetworkItems">
        <nb-accordion-item-header>
          ...some content
        </nb-accordion-item-header>
        <nb-accordion-item-body>
          ...some content
        </nb-accordion-item-body>
      </nb-accordion-item>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</nb-accordion>
```

can you help me?

Comment: `ng-template` does not render any thing. You're looking for `ng-container`,(the use of ng-template is giving a reference variable and choose between two options see e.g. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a basic mistake of using `model.ItemsType` instead of `model.itemtype`

StackBlitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-template-reference

For those who are thinking that `ng-template` cannot be used with `*ngIf` see the accepted answer at [why *ngIf doesnt'work with ng-template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837756/why-ngif-doesntwork-with-ng-template) where the syntactical sugar format `*ngIf` is replaced with `[ngIf]` directive (but is not advised).