# TypeError: “ctx.activeUser is undefined”

Tags: angular

I'm working on an admin app and I'm currently trying to hide some routes depending on the role of the

admin. for some unknown reasons the template is rendering before the subscription is resolved.

I tried wrapping the template with ng-container, still getting the same error.

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="activeUser">
      <li class="nav-link"> <i class="text-center icon-speedometer pr-2"></i>Dashboard</li>
      <div *ngIf="role === 'Accountant'">
        <li class="nav-link title">ACCOUNTS</li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/paysim-transactions"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>Paysim Transactions</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/pos-transactions"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>POS Transactions</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/reversal-logs"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>Reversal Logs</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/customers"><i class="text-center icon-user pr-2"></i>View Customers</a></li>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="role === 'Customer Success'">
        <li class="nav-link title">CUSTOMER SUCCESS</li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/agents"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>View Agents</a> </li>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="role === 'Super Admin'">
        <li class="nav-link title">ADMIN</li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/admin"><i class="text-center icon-settings pr-2"></i>Settings</a> </li>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

  activeUser;
  activeUserChecker = false;
  role;



  getActiveUser() {
    this.connection.creating = true;
    this.adminService.getActiveUser().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.activeUser = data;
      this.role = data.role;
      this.activeUserChecker = true;
      this.connection.creating = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getActiveUser();
  }
```

Comment: **1.** You say you're using `ng-container` in the question, but in the code you're using `ng-template`. **2.** The property in question `ctx.activeUser` is nowhere to be found in the code provided.

Comment: that happened during some trial and error, still got the same error message.

Comment: The second question is still unanswered. What is `ctx` in this context? It is nowhere to be found in the code you've provided.

Comment: that's an angular error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that it take more time for the browser to fetch the data you're asking for than serving your html content.

The best way to be sure that the subscription has ended in your template would be to use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```js
  activeUser$;
  activeUserChecker = false;
  role;



  getActiveUser() {
    this.connection.creating = true;
    this.activeUser$ = this.adminService.getActiveUser();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getActiveUser();
  }
```

```html
    <ng-container *ngIf="activeUser$ | async">
      <li class="nav-link"> <i class="text-center icon-speedometer pr-2"></i>Dashboard</li>
      <div *ngIf="(activeUser$ | async).role === 'Accountant'">
        <li class="nav-link title">ACCOUNTS</li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/paysim-transactions"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>Paysim Transactions</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/pos-transactions"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>POS Transactions</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/reversal-logs"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>Reversal Logs</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/customers"><i class="text-center icon-user pr-2"></i>View Customers</a></li>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="role === 'Customer Success'">
        <li class="nav-link title">CUSTOMER SUCCESS</li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/agents"><i class="text-center icon-chart pr-2"></i>View Agents</a> </li>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="role === 'Super Admin'">
        <li class="nav-link title">ADMIN</li>
        <li class="nav-link "> <a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="/admin"><i class="text-center icon-settings pr-2"></i>Settings</a> </li>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: hello thanks for your contribution, I got an error:

Identifier 'role' is not defined. 'T' does not contain such a member

on this line:

```
<div *ngIf="(activeUser$ | async).role === 'Accountant'">
```

Comment: ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: did you remove the subscription in your ts file ? how did you define your service method ? does it return specificly a Observable<T> where T is your type

Comment: turns out I wasn't returning an observable in my service method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
As stated in 
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives
https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

The asterisk, *, syntax on a structural directive, such as *ngIf, is shorthand that Angular interprets into a longer form. Angular transforms the asterisk in front of a structural directive into an <ng-template> that surrounds the host element and its descendants.

Reference :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837756/why-ngif-doesntwork-with-ng-template

You can use it as:
<div *ngIf="condition; else otherTemplate">
...
</div>
<ng-template #otherTemplate>
</ng-template>
```